# DELPHI MVC (BCE)

Tags: delphi, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, delphi-xe5

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como implementar o pattern MVC (BCE) em Delphi.
Uso DelphiXE5 E gostaria de deixá-lo o mais escalável possível, e sei que uma das soluções é torná-lo uma aplicação MVC.
Alguma sugestão? Fonte ? Exemplo?

Obrigado!

Comment: Escalável em qual sentido? MVC é só a divisão da regra em camadas de visualização, negócio e persistência. Não necessariamente escalável. A aplicação vai ser feita utilizando DataSnap? REST?

Comment: Escalável no sentido de futuramente poder adicionar novos módulos, herdando ou não de classes que já foram implementadas sem dificuldades para realizar a adição deste módulo.
Ainda não foi definido se utilizaremos DataSnap ou REST, estou apenas fazendo uma pesquisa para tentar encontrar as melhores maneiras de desenvolver nosso produto.

Answer (score 2):

Bom eu Particularmente nunca desenvolvi em Mvc com Delphi, Mas encontrei este exemplo na web [Apostila Delphi Mvc](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDsQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Flazarus-br.googlecode.com%2Fsvn%2Ftrunk%2Fdoc%2FMVC%2520Delphi.pdf&ei=kpLaU5WkBvDhsASZ5IDgAg&usg=AFQjCNG0PwhOlc9LkiDlMURhU9b6ADJT7w&bvm=bv.72185853,d.b2U), Para desenvolver em Mvc basicamente é mais a separação dos objetos em camadas para isso o projeto todo terá de ser orientado a objeto Manipulando e devolvendo objetos como qualuqer outra linguagem até ai normal, a Unica coisa que a forma de criar, herdar, sobrecarga no delphi é um pouco diferente então muitos se assustam com isso.

Answer (score 2):

O modelo MVC destina-se a construção de interfaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) e não de toda a arquitetura da aplicação. Outros modelos podem também chegar ao mesmo resultado e os argumentos colocados por você não necessariamente serão atingidos unicamente por fazer uso deste modelo.

Questões relativas a regras de negócio e persistência não são cobertas por MVC, visto que o propósito principal dele é construir objetos de interação com o usuário que permitam o uso de testes unitários durante sua implementação.

É considerado um erro implementar regras de negócio em um *controller* tanto quanto seria errado implementá-las em um *form* e pelos mesmos motivos.

A implementação de regras de negócio pode ficar localizada em diversas partes da aplicação dependendo do modelo arquitetural escolhido. Por exemplo, se você for fazer uso de DDD (Domain-Driven Design) então as regras de negócio serão implementadas em classes de domínio e classes de serviços, enquanto que a persistência será administrada por repositórios, fazendo ou não uso de um sistema de persistência automática.

Existe um produto em https://code.google.com/p/delphimvcframework/

Answer (score -1):

Ver o modelo MVCBr - um framework delphi/MVC.   http://www.tireideletra.com.br  através de um conjunto de assistentes mostrar como aplicar na prática o conceito em app no padrão MVC.